# Error (401) Login Required - Google Calendar API v3

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I want to add an event to a particular Google Apps calendar each time that an appointment is booked in my codeigniter app.

So far I've gone through the following steps (from [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)):

1. Add Google API Client Library to application/third_party
2. Create Service Account in Developer Console with Google Apps Domain-wide Delegation enabled
3. Store provided .p12 file
4. Authorize Service Account Client ID in Google Apps Admin Console with scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`
5. Share calendar with Service Account email address

I'm getting the error "Error calling POST `<calendar API insert endpoint>` (401) Login Required"

I believe that I must be doing something incorrect in how I'm authenticating. Any advice would be welcomed.

application/libraries/Google.php:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
set_include_path(APPPATH . 'third_party/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require_once APPPATH . 'third_party/Google/autoload.php';
require_once APPPATH . 'third_party/Google/Client.php';

class Google extends Google_Client {
    function __construct($params = array()) {
        parent::__construct();

        $client_email = '<SERVICE ACCOUNT EMAIL>';
        $private_key = file_get_contents('<.P12 FILE PATH>');
        $scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');

        $credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
            $client_email,
            $scopes,
            $private_key
        );

        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
        if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
          $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
        }
    }
}
```

application/controllers/Booking.php:

(Google.php library loaded in constructor)

```
function addCalendarEvent($user_id, $date, $time, $address, $booking_data) {

    $cal = new Google_Service_Calendar($this->google);

    $calendar_id = '<CALENDAR ID>';

    $start_datetime = date('c', strtotime($date.' '.$time));

    $end_datetime = date('c', strtotime($date.' '.$time.' +2 hours'));

    $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
      'summary' => 'Appointment at '.$address['street_address'],
      'location' => $location,
      'description' => $booking_data['description'],
      'start' => array(
        'dateTime' => $start_datetime,
        'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
      ),
      'end' => array(
        'dateTime' => $end_datetime,
        'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
      ),
      'attendees' => array(
        array('email' => '<ADMIN EMAIL>')
      )
    ));

    $cal->events->insert($calendar_id, $event);
}
```

Comment: check what $this->google is.  it should be $client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my own problem by instantiating `Google_Service_Calendar` before authenticating, like so:

```
class Google extends Google_Client {
    function __construct($params = array()) {
        parent::__construct();

        $client_email = '<SERVICE ACCOUNT EMAIL>';
        $private_key = file_get_contents('<.P12 FILE PATH>');
        $scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar');

        $client = new Google_Client();

        $this->cal = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

        $credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
            $client_email,
            $scopes,
            $private_key
        );

        $client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
        if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
          $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
        }
    }
}
```

And then using the service in application/controllers/Booking.php like so:

```
$this->google->cal->events->insert($calendar_id, $event);
```