# Enable auto Video Link in Google Calendar API

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use the Google Calendar API to generate Hangouts link dynamically. For this, the account being used for authentication (say account ***A***) must have Auto Video link option enabled under calendar settings.

So, when I try to use the Service Account for authentication, everything works fine and the event is created but the `hangoutLink` in the response is `NULL` and when I try to use the `API_KEY` (of the same account ***A***) for authentication I get unauthenticated error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Login Required", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Login Required" } }

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("MY APP NAME");
$client->setDeveloperKey("MY_API_KEY");
$client->setScopes("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar");
```

Is there any way to enable the auto video option for the service account **or** to fix the 401?

Comment: Have you checked the related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34218789/error-401-login-required-google-calendar-api-v3)? Same error was encountered. **`"Error calling POST <calendar API insert endpoint> (401) Login Required"`**

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 thanks for replying, that wasn't the case with me, the problem was that, goggle has `3` ways of authenticating **1.)** using `setDeveloperKey` which i was using, **2.)** using `OAuth`, **3.)** using service account. I was getting 401 in #1, and that was because `event` creation couldn't be done using `API_KEY` you have to use either use `#2` or `#3`, solved the issue using `#2` with `accessType` set to `offline`. Also, I tried `setDeveloperKey` and it was working for  Google Books apis (i tried simple searches).

Comment: did you got output for this